# Simple future value calculator problems in php

Tags: php

I'm having trouble understanding why my php program for class is not working. I've looked through a lot of documentation and I think i'm including it right but it says fail to open stream on the include and when I call the function it says it's undefined could someone please point out my probably very simple error here. here is my php page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\program1include.php' ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Future Value Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
Principal <input type="text" name="principal" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['principal'])) echo $_POST['principal']; ?>"><br />
Interest Rate <input type="text" name="rate" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['rate'])) echo $_POST['rate']; ?>"><br />
Years to Invest <input type="text" name="years" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['years'])) echo $_POST['years']; ?>"><br />
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Get Future Value.' /><br />
Future Value:
<?php figureValue(); if(isset($futureValue)){
    echo $futureValue;
}
    else
    {
        echo 'Please Fill Out All Fields.';
    }
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

HERE IS THE INCLUDE

```
<?php 
    function figureValue($principal,$rate,$years){

        $futureValue = round($principal * pow(1 + ($rate/100),
        $years), 2);
    }
    ?>
```

the page outputs

Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\program1include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\program1php.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\program1include.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\program1php.php on line 2
Principal 
Interest Rate 
Years to Invest

Future Value: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function figureValue() in C:\xampp\htdocs\program1php.php on line 16

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$futureValue` is local to the function. Assigning it there does not set the variable in the main program. You need to return it:

```
function figureValue($principal,$rate,$years){

    $futureValue = round($principal * pow(1 + ($rate/100), $years), 2);
    return $futureValue;
}
```

You also need to pass the `$_POST` paramaters as arguments to the function.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['Submit']) { $futureValue = figureValue($_POST['principle'], $_POST['rate'], $_POST['years']);
    echo $futureValue;
}
    else
    {
        echo 'Please Fill Out All Fields.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I did this and it corrected an error that I know I was going to have i'd written that wrong but it still isn't letting me run the function because I cant get it included.

Comment: If you change the `include` statement to just use the filename, with no directory, and it's in the same directory as the main script, it should work. If not, you must be mistyping something.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of the `include` line.

Comment: @Barmar the semicolon is not needed since it is one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

try escaping the include like

`C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\program1include.php`

change

`<?php include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\program1include.php' ?>`

to

`<?php include 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\program1include.php'; ?>`

Comment: what do you mean by "escaping the include"?

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh ok trying it

Comment: If that were the problem the error wouldn't say `C:\xampp\htdocs\program1include.php` it would say `C:xampphtdocsprogram1include.php`

Comment: Did you get a different error or the same error? I think you need to do this and what Barmar is saying.

Comment: same error now i changed it to <?php if (isset($_POST['Submit']) { $futureValue = figureValue($_POST['principle'], $_POST['rate'], $_POST['years']);
    echo $futureValue;
}
    else
    {
        echo 'Please Fill Out All Fields.';
    }
?>

Answer (score 0):

If the two files are in same directory, just use the name of the file, not the entire path.

```
include 'program1include.php'
```

I copied your code exactly and changed the one line above and received no warning.
You don't want to access the file system in your script (c:).

Things to check

That both files are in the same directory.
That each file is named exactly like you have above.(Rename them something simple to check)

Barmar is correct. Without his edit, the program still will not run.

Comment: Why dont you start by pasting the function at the top of your page and skip the include all together.

Comment: So both files are in same directory? And you checked the spelling? And the case? What about Changing from back slash to forward slash?